# The measure of a function defined on digits

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f:[0,1)\times[0,1)\to [0,\infty]$ is the function where $f(x,y)$ is the number of digits (base 2) where $x$ and $y$ disagree. Ignore cases where we have infinitely many $1$'s to ensure uniqueness of binary expansion. I want to show that $f$ is measurable, and indeed, find the Lebesgue measure of $f^{-1}([0,\infty))$.

My idea to show $f$ measurable was to write $$f(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1_{R_n(x)\ne R_n(y)}$$

Where $R_n(x)$ is the $n^{th}$ digit of $x$. I have previosuly shown that $R_n$ measurable for all $n$. So I want to show that each $1_{R_n(x)\ne R_n(y)}$ measurable, i.e. that $$\{(x,y)|R_n(x)\ne R_n(y)\}$$
measurable, and then presumably use some lemma to the effect that the infinite sum of non-negative measurable functions is measurable. But I'm not sure how to show the above set is measurable, or even to describe it really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A(n)$ be $f^{-1}(\ \{n\}\ )$.

A description of $A(n)$ is as follows. Consider all possible ordered $n$-tuples $k$ in $\Bbb N$, i.e. of indices for the decimals of a binary number in $I:=[0,1]$,
$$k=(k_1<k_2<\dots<k_n)\ .$$
They build a countable set $K(n)$, a subset of $\Bbb N^{\times n}$.
For each such $k\in K(n)$ consider
$$A(n,k)=\Big\{\ (x,y)\in[0,1]^2\ :\ x,y\text{ differ exactly at the "places" }k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n\ \}\ .
$$
It is clear that $A(n,k)$ is measurable, and
$$
f^{-1}(n)=A(n)=\bigsqcup _{k\in K(n)}A(n,k)\ .
$$
For this, one may consider the "$k$-switch" map $S(n,k):I\to I$, defined almost everywhere, which associates to an $x\in I$ the (almost always) unique element $y=S(n,k)(x)\in I$, which differs in its binary representation from $x$ at the places in $k$.

Then $A(n,k)$ is the graph of $S(n,k)$, so it has measure zero.

The second part of the problem asks for the measure of 
$$
\{f<\infty\}\ =\ 
\bigsqcup _{n\ge 0}
\bigsqcup _{k\in K(n)} A(n,k)
\ .$$
A countable union of zero sets.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- The sum or difference of two measurable functions is measurable.
- The inverse image of an open set under a measurable function is measurable.
- For any $m < \infty$,  $\{(x,y) \mid f(x,y) \ge m\}$ is the union of a countable family of measurable sets, therefore is measurable.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but that's not really the hard bit. As the codomain is just $\mathbb{N}$ we just need to show $f^{-1}(n)$ Borel for all $n$. But this seems very difficult in practice, i.e. what even is $f^{-1}(3)$? It looks extremely hard to describe.

Comment: @ElieBergman $f^{-1}(3)$ is a countable union of sets "$x$ and $y$  differ exactly at positions $n_1,n_2,n_3$". With fixed $n_1,n_2,n_3$ and choices which of $x,y$ has $0$ or $1$ there, that should be easier to describe